# how do i include non chef resources using chefspec

Tags: chef-infra, chefspec

i want to write chefspec for one of the recipe which has the code to create jenkins user as shown below.

```
    jenkins_user 'test1' do
      full_name   'test user'
      email     'test1@test.com'
      password      'testp' 
    end
```

Here  "jenkins_user" is not a chef resource. how do i write a chefspec to run a unit test on the recipe.

or if we have anyother way to run a unit test for the recipe kindly let me know.

Comment: You may read the docs about [Testing LWRP with ChefSpec](https://github.com/sethvargo/chefspec#testing-lwrps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are including resources that are defined in another cookbook, if the cookbook author has written a `libraries/matchers.rb` file then you can call those matchers in your ChefSpec unit tests.

For example, if you are using the [Jenkins Community Cookbook](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/jenkins) you will see there is already a `matchers.rb` file located [here](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/jenkins/blob/8c2eaa74ab3375c8cddb574579c0e2b6ed6fd327/libraries/matchers.rb). So, you should be able to create unit tests like this:

```
it 'should create the jenkins user' do
  expect(chef_run).to create_jenkins_user('test1')
end
```

If you are including resources from a cookbook that does not have matchers defined, then you will have to write your own matchers, and the details for doing this are in the documentation which Tensibai linked to.